# Kendo UI : how create window with others components

Tags: kendo-ui

I want create a kendo window with 2 components : kendo multiselect and kendo upload.

```
$("#win").kendoWindow({
  actions: ["Close"],
  draggable: false,
  modal: true,
  pinned: false,
  resizable: true,
  title: "Window with components",
  width: "40%",
  height: "40%"
}).data("kendoWindow");
```

What the best way ? How to do ?
Do you have a little sample ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: add the 2 comopnents in your div with the id #win. Have you done that.

Comment: ok but if I open many times ... it doesn't work very well

Comment: how should it work? can you explain in more detail.

Comment: in fact it works http://dojo.telerik.com/@lgoubet/UnAguDez but in my project I have a another problems I'm going to verify the reasons why thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to give you a full answer as this is a stepping stone for you to continue learning and figuring out it, but you can just include other components within the actual `<div>` of your window.  This is essentially the basics of HTML.

```js
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Apples" },
    { name: "Oranges" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "name"
});

$("#win").kendoWindow({
  actions: ["Close"],
  draggable: true,
  modal: true,
  pinned: false,
  resizable: true,
  title: "Window with components",
  width: "40%",
  height: "40%"
}).data("kendoWindow");
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id='win'>
  <div id='multiselect'></div>
  <!-- More components -->
</div>
```

Comment: yes ok but ok but if I open many times ... it doesn't work very well the multiselect is recreated  ... i'm going use the template